# Simple javascript in a cshtml page MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Well, i had enough with this, it's not working.

I want to check these checkboxes all at once using javascript, in a **.cshtml** page.

The checkboxes are part of a table :

```
<td>@Html.CheckBox(idPanier.ToString(),false, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "ckb" }) </td>
```

And my javascript function is up in my page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    checkAll = function (source) {

    $(".ckb input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', "checked");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is it a typo `@class="ckb"` or do you have a parent element with class `chk` as in your jQuery selector `$(".chk input[type='checkbox']")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the below will check all the check boxes for you.

```
let checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

let checkAll = function (source) {
    source.each(function (index, element) {
    $(element).prop('checked', 'checked')
  });
}

checkAll(checkboxes);
```

jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/yyqp712c/

Comment: It dosen't check specific checkboxes, it check them all... but that's what i need right now so... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, without looking at the html your cshtml page generates, I'd say the issue is with your selector:
`".chk input[type='checkbox']"`
This is looking for inputs of `type="checkbox"` *underneath* your `.chk`s.

Try something like `$("input[type='checkbox'].chk")` maybe? Or even just `$(".chk")`?